# Why did God Shiva drink kalkut or halahal but not any other God(s) or Goddess(es)?

Tags: shiva, samudra-manthan

Like God Shiva, God Vishnu and God Brahma(i.e. tridev)  and the tridevis has equal power  then why did God Shiva had to drink the poison that also alone?